# Calcular quantas vezes se repetem os valores dentro de uma KEY em dicionário - PYTHON

Tags: python, dicionário

Eu tenho um dicionário que é criado a partir de um select no banco de dados, o que eu precisava era gerar uma métrica a partir desse dicionário

**Dicionário**

```
# cria dicionário do banco de dados com os valores
lds_data = {}
for lds_item in db_result:
    lds_data.update({lds_item[1] : {'code_client' : lds_item[0], 'city' : lds_item[2]}})
```

**Saída do Dicinário:**

```
u'BRASIL_ALIMEN': {'code_client': u'BRA', 'city': u'SAO PAULO'},
u'BRASIL_CARROS': {'code_client': u'BRC', 'city': u'PARANA'}
```

**Exemplo da métrica:**

> **code_client:** *BRA* aparece *1x* dentro do dicionário

**Resumindo:**

Preciso calcular quantas vezes se repetem os valores dentro da **KEY** = `*code_client*`

**Tentei fazer da seguinte forma:**

```
ct = {}
for key in lds_data:
    ct['code_client'] = len(lds_data[key]['code_client'])
```

Comment: Chegou a usar um `count`ou `if` para fazer a contagem?

Comment: Só consegui assim: print(len(lds_data.keys()))

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessa documentação: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: for item in lds_data:
        clients = Counter(lds_data[item]['code_client'])
        print(clients)

Ja testei, porém sem sucesso...

Comment: Se voce entender ingles, dê uma olhada nessa pergunta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705829/count-repeated-keys-in-a-dict

Comment: vou dar uma olhada, obrigado!

Comment: Luis, pelas suas últimas perguntas aqui no site acho que você precisa estudar SQL. Você pode pegar a contagem de repetições diretamente pelo banco de dados, é muito mais performático. A não ser que você esteja aprendendo python e não queira usar SQL propositalmente.

Comment: Infelizmente eu não posso usar o SQL, eu tenho que fazer em python no back-end... Seria muito mais rápido fazer direto no BD, mas infelizmente n posso, mas obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Mas de onde vem o `db_result`?

Comment: Um banco de dados DB2

Comment: Não foi isso que quis dizer... O `db_result` é o resultado de uma query feita pelo python em um banco de dados... Você não consegue modificar essa query?

Comment: Ah tá, desculpa, n tinha entendido, eu consigo, mas n posso realizar uma query diferente da que me foi passada, só posso trabalhar em cima do script

Comment: @LuisV. respondi a pergunta com 3 maneiras de fazer a contagem de ocorrência em iteráveis. Qualquer dúvida é só perguntar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para realizar uma contagem de `code_client` dos seus registros usando python você pode usar:

1. a classe `collections.Counter`
2. um dicionário comum
3. a classe `collections.default_dict`
4. *…alguma outra solução que desconheço…*

---

Para os exemplos a seguir, usarei uma sequência de tuplas para simular o retorno de um `SELECT` no banco de dados… Os dados fictícios são:

```
dados = (
    ('BRA', 'BRASIL_ALIMEN', 'SAO_PAULO'),
    ('BRA', 'BRASIL_CARROS', 'PARANA'),
    ('BRA', 'BRASIL_NAVIOS', 'PARAIBA'),
    ('CAN', 'CANADA_ALIMEN', 'ALBERTA'),
    ('USA', 'USA_CARROS', 'MASSACHUSSETS'),
    ('USA', 'USA_NAVIOS', 'CALIFORNIA'),
    ('UK', 'UK_NAVIOS', 'YORK'),
)
```

Nos exemplos que seguem, contarei a ocorrência do primeiro elemento das tuplas, como `BRA`, `CAN`, etc…

---

### Conhecimentos necessários

Nos exemplos das respostas faço uso de [*list comprehensions*](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)<sup>*</sup> e *iterable unpacking* (veja a [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) para mais informações).

Mas para fins de clareza, segue uma breve demonstração de como os uso nas respostas abaixo:

```
# cria uma lista normal
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# Usa uma list comprehension para criar outra lista
list_comprehension = [-x for x in lista]
# list_comprehension = [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5]

# Usa iterable unpacking para "quebrar a lista em pedaços"
um, dois, *restante = lista
# um = 1
# dois = 2
# restante = (3, 4, 5)
```

Com estas informações, acredito que os código a seguir não serão problema.

<sup>* na verdade é uma [*generator expressions*](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), mas vai ficar muito mais fácil entender *generator expressions*, *dict comprehensions* e suas variações, se você entender *list comprehensions*.</sup>

---

### 1. Usando `collections.Counter` ([#Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter))

A classe `Counter` é uma subclasse de `dict`, o dicionário padrão do python, que serve como um contador para objetos *hashable*.

Podemos criar um contador a partir de um iterável qualquer, como uma lista, tupla ou, por exemplo, uma string:

```
from collections import Counter

contador = Counter("abracadabra")
# Counter({'a': 5, 'b': 2, 'r': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1})
```

Dessa maneira podemos fazer com que `Counter` conte apenas os primeiros elementos de uma tupla com o seguinte código:

```
from collections import Counter

contador = Counter(cod_cliente for cod_cliente, *_ in dados)
# contador = Counter({'BRA': 3, 'USA': 2, 'CAN': 1, 'UK': 1})
```

Lembrando que:

```
[cod_cliente for cod_cliente, *_ in dados]
# ['BRA', 'BRA', 'BRA', 'CAN', 'USA', 'USA', 'UK']
```

---

### 2. Usando `dict` ([#Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict))

Podemos usar um dicionário comum para adicionar a soma das ocorrência a medida que iteramos sobre `dados`.

Para isso basta tratarmos quando a chave ainda não existe no dicionário, pois se tentarmos pegar uma chave inexiste, [`dict.__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?#object.__getitem__) invocará [`dict.__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?#object.__missing__) que  lançará a exceção [`KeyError`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#KeyError). Exemplos:

```
dicionario = {'teste': 10}

# 1) Atualiza uma chave existente (OK)
dicionario['teste'] = dicionario['teste'] + 1
# dicionario = {'teste': 11}

# 2) Atualiza uma chave inexistente (erro)
dicionario["outra-chave"] = dicionario["outra-chave"] + 1
#                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# KeyError: 'outra-chave' não existe em 'dicionario'

# 3) Testando antes de usar a chave (OK)
if 'outra-chave' not in dicionario:
    dicionario["outra-chave"] = 0

dicionario["outra-chave"] += 1
# dicionario = {'teste': 11, 'outra-chave': 1}
```

Você também poderia usar a exceção [`KeyError`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) para tratar estes casos. Exemplo:

```
dicionario = {}
try:
    dicionario['teste'] += 1
except KeyError:
    dicionario['teste'] = 1
```

Porém, dicionários possuem o método [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) que recebe os argumentos `dict.get(key, default)`, onde `key` é a chave do dicionário que você quer ler e `default` é o valor que será retornado caso esta chave não exista.

No nosso caso, queremos somar 1 unidade ao valor atual da chave, porém se a chave não existir queremos que este valor seja 0. Veja em prática:

```
dicionario = {}

dicionario['teste'] += 1
# KeyError
dicionario['teste'] = dicionario['teste'] + 1
# KeyError

dicionario['teste'] = dicionario.get('teste', 0) + 1
# dicionario = {'teste': 1}
```

Dessa maneira, se a chave ainda não existir, cria a nova chave com o devido valor.

O código final ficaria:

```
contador = {}

for code_client, *_ in dados:
    contador[code_client] = contador.get(code_client, 0) + 1

# contador = {'BRA': 3, 'CAN': 1, 'USA': 2, 'UK': 1}
```

---

### 3. Usando `defaultdict` ([#Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict))

Assim como o `collections.Counter` mencionando anteriormente, `default_dict` também é uma subclasse de `dict`.

A classe `defaultdict` tem um atributo `default_factory` que deve ser um objeto invocável ou `None`.

Por padrão, ao acessar um chave inexistente, o método [`dict.__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?#object.__getitem__) invoca o método [`dict.__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?#object.__missing__), e este lança uma exceção [`KeyError`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#KeyError).
Já o `defaultdict` sobrescreve o método [`dict.__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?#object.__missing__) para invocar `defaultdict.default_factory` e usar o seu retorno como valor padrão caso a chave não exista.

Um resumo:

```
dicionario = {}
valor = dicionario['teste']
# 1. invoca dicionario.__getitem__('teste')
# 2. chave não existe, então invoca dicionario.__missing__('teste')
# 3. dict.__missing__ lança uma KeyError
# KeyError
```

Agora `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# função que será a 'default_factory' do defaultdict
def valor_padrao():
    return "Valor padrão"

dicionario = defaultdict(valor_padrao)
valor = dicionario['teste']
# 1. invoca dicionario.__getitem__('teste')
# 2. chave não existe, então invoca dicionario.__missing__('teste')
# 3. defaultdict.default_factory é um objeto invocável, então retorna o resultado do método
# 4. dicionario['teste'] = dicionario.default_factory()
# 5. valor = dicionario['teste']
# valor = 'Valor padrão'
```

Se `defaultdict.default_factory` for `None`, `defaultdict` se comporta da mesma maneira que `dict` e lançará uma [`KeyError`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) em chaves inexistentes.

Para o nosso código final, basta criar uma função que retorne zero e usá-la como `default_factory`. Para a nossa comodidade a função `int`, se invocada sem parâmetros, retorna zero. Então o código final usando `defaultdict` ficaria:

```
contador = defaultdict(int)

for code_client, *_ in dados:
    contador[code_client] += 1

# contador = defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'BRA': 3, 'CAN': 1, 'USA': 2, 'UK': 1})
```

---

Estas foram 3 maneiras de você contar as repetições que você recebe do seu banco de dados, mas vale lembrar para futuros visitantes que utilizar `GROUP BY` e `COUNT` na sua *query* é muito mais performático.

Criei este [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-407476-6333) com os 3 exemplos rodando, caso seja do interesse de alguém.

Answer (score 0):

recorri a perguntar na gringa, a solução está abaixo:

**Solução**

```
ct = {}
for _, value in lds_data.items():
    if value['code_client'] in ct:
        ct [value['code_client']] += 1
    else:
        ct [value['code_client']] = 1
```

Comment: Se vai ignorar as chaves do dicionário, poderia fazer somente `for value in lds_data.values()`