# Numero de repetições em uma lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, matriz, lista-encadeada

Preciso resolver o seguinte exercício:
Faça uma função chamada `contaPalavras`. Essa função deve receber uma lista como entrada.

Cada elemento da lista recebida pela função é uma outra lista de palavras.

A função deve retornar o total de palavras sem contar as repetições, a palavra que mais se repetiu e a palavra que menos repetiu.

até agora eu fiz o seguinte:

```
def contaPalavras(lista):
ord = [] 
rep=[]
total=0
 
for sublist in lista: 
    for val in sublist: 
        ord.append(val)         
ord=sorted(ord)  
  
repeticoes=0
for x in range(0,len(ord)-1):
   if ord[x]==ord[x+1]:
     repeticoes+=1
     if x == len(ord)-2:
       print(ord[x],',',repeticoes+1)
   else:
     print(ord[x],',',repeticoes+1)
     repeticoes=0
```

a lista utilizada foi:

```
lista = [
    ['Angola','Chade','Gana'],
    ['Chade','Angola','Gana','Togo'],
    ['Togo','Gana','Chade','Eritreia'],
    ['Chade','Togo','Angola']
]
```

até agora eu consigo printar o número de repetições, mas não sei como pegar o que mais se repete, o que menos se repete e o total da lista sem as repetições

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: [Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/407476/6333) eu explico algumas formas de contar repetições usando dicionários... Você pode entender como funciona e adaptar para o seu caso.

Answer (score -1):

vamos começar com a lista de palavras sem repetição.
Crie um array novo, ele irá conter as palavras que não serão repetidas.

```
palavras_sem_repeticao = []
```

Agora, verifique se a palavra que será adicionada já está contida no array novo.

```
if palavra not in palavras_sem_repeticao:
    palavras_sem_repeticao.append(palavra)
else: 
    print(f"A palavra {palavra} já foi armazenada")
```

Para encontrar as palavras que mais foram repetidas, você precisará de um array que contenha TODAS essas palavras.
Agora, verifique o número de vezes que a palavra 'x' se repete dentro desse array.
Ex.

```
array_completo = ["banana", "pera", "banana", "laranja"]
array_completo.count("banana") # deverá retornar 2
```

Crie um laço de repetição que verifica todas as palavras, e em seguida você terá o número de vezes que cada palavra se repete dentro do array, agora basta pegar o maior e menor valor.